# How to run a jenkins project to run on multiple slaves?

Tags: jenkins, distributed-system

I have configured Jenkins in my machine (master). In master machine, i have created Jenkins project. Later i have added two slaves and named the label as "windows" for both. Slaves connected to the master. Also, i set this label to the Jenkins project to the option "Restrict where this project can be run".

Now i triggered the Jenkins build for two times and check. This build is run in only one slave and the second time triggered build is in pending to run in the same slave.

I have removed the label which i set in Jenkins project to run in any slaves which is free. That too not worked. If i triggered the same Jenkins project 2 times, one build running and another one not running.

I have searched about this and the solution i got is not a successful one. Could anyone please clear me about this how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what you did seems to be the correct way of doing it. Do you allow the build to be run concurrently? Otherwise that is the problem...

Another issue, Jenkins will always choose the last successful slave for a build if it is possible. I don't think this is your issue but might be good to know. So if you start in 14 times in a row and you don't allow concurrent run, they will all run on the same slave.